# Quarkus liveness doesn't work on Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus, minikube

When I run locally (mvn compile quarkus:dev), I can access the /q/health endpoints. When I deploy the native image to docker (docker run etc etc), I can access the /q/health endpoints. When I deploy to minikube, I can't access the /q/health endpoints.

What is strange is that I can access / to get the index.html page, but the /q/health returns a 404. I'm new to Quarkus, and am not an expert in Kubernetes.

In addition, the liveness endpoint isn't even accessible to Kubernetes liveness check, causing the pod to immediately restart since /q/health/live is not available.

EXPECTED:
/r/health/live accessible to Kubernetes cluster
/r/health/live accessible via browser

ACTUAL:
/r/health/live not accessible to Kubernetes cluster
/r/health/live returns 404 via browser

Is there something obviously dumb I'm doing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the 404 coming from Quarkus?

Comment: As far as I can tell? I'll dig into that. I'll verify what Quarkus does on a 404 in dev mode to see if it logs something and compare.

Comment: Update - looks like if it gets to Quarkus it will logs something when I have access logs turned on. It's not even getting to Quarkus, it seems. As I suspected, this is more of a Kubernetes/minikube thing I need to learn better.

Comment: Update - Using Docker Kubernetes locally instead of minikube locally seems to work. I see in the pod logs: 2023-09-07 21:12:04,235 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (executor-thread-2) 10.1.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2023:21:12:04 +0000] "GET /q/health/live HTTP/1.1" 200 135
2023-09-07 21:12:04,235 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (executor-thread-1) 10.1.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2023:21:12:04 +0000] "GET /q/health/ready HTTP/1.1" 200 45

Comment: Update - I'm not sure what I did exactly, but it's working now. I installed the kubernetes.yml on minikube and that seemed to show the 200 responses in the logs, and then I redeployed using minikube.yml and was able to get everything working. I must have had some state in minikube floating around that I didn't realize was still there.

Answer (score 0):

Steps I took to get around this:

1. Start over and read https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-kubernetes. Update application.properties. Now I've got a command I can execute, that:

> - builds the Quarkus project
> - pushes the image to my public Docker repo,
> - and generates the YAML for both Kubernetes and Minikube deployments.

2. Try deploying to Docker's version of Kubernetes after enabling Kubernetes on Docker Desktop. Use kubernetes.yml. Verified that the health endpoints were accessible by Kubernetes itself by looking at pod logs.
3. Try deploying to Minikube again. Delete everything in the cluster. Use minikube.yml to get Pod, Deployment and Service.
4. Use "kubectl port-forward svc/ 8080:http" to forward to the service instead of the pod.
5. Verified that Kubernetes could access the health endpoints internally by viewing pod logs.
6. Verified I could access the health endpoints externally via browser.